# Publish content of referenced project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, clickonce, visual-studio-2013

Using Visual Studio 2013 (but I have this problem in 2010, and 2012) I wanted to give click-once a go and see if it was worth my troubles. I think it could be, but I'm not 100% sure yet. I created a new wpf project called PublishClickOnceTest and then added an existing project to the solution. The existing project has a DLL that is marked as Content. I put a text block in my application to see if the dll was present. That dll is required for the referenced project of mine to work. On my development PC it comes back as true, but when I install it on my tablet it says false. I've searched around and everyone says mark it as content.. well it is. So I'm not sure why it isn't grabbing this content file. Does anyone know how to make it do this?

Comment: Is the DLL included in the Application files that are published?  This is set in the Publish tab of the main application.  If it is not is not set to Include, it won't be push to the client.

Comment: @ScottWylie No it is not, which is what I was figuring what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2013, you should find that items marked with the **build action** set to **content** [are included by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy0fky2.aspx):

> Files with the Build Action property set to Content are designated as
>   application files and will be marked as included by default. They can
>   be included, excluded, or marked as data files.

However, in older versions you used to have to set it to Copy Always. To do this you can use the property viewer of the item in your Solution Explorer, then you set **Copy to output directory** to `Copy Always`.

Comment: I changed said flag from Copy if newer to Copy Always, and no dice :/